# Почему файлы, в тексте которых нет русских символов, не кодируются в UTF-8 без BOM?

Tags: кодировка, php, notepad++, utf-8

Здравствуйте.

Решил перекодировать свои PHP-файлы в UTF-8. Приходится каждый файл перекодировать вручную. Открываю файл, выбираю - "Преобразовать в UTF-8 без BOM", далее сохраняю и закрываю редактируемый файл. Но. Открываю тот же файл ещё раз, смотрю кодировку и снова там вижу кодировку ANSI. Хотя я только что его преобразовал в UTF-8 без BOM. Такое у меня наблюдается только с теми файлами, в тексте которых нет русских символов. А файлы с русскими символами преобразуются нормально.

Почему файлы, в тексте которых нет русских символов, не кодируются в UTF-8 без BOM? Спасибо.

Comment: Все очень просто - если у Вас только латинница (то есть символы с кодами до 127 включительно) и без BOM, то отличить ansi от UTF-8 нельзя. Они идентичны. Возможно, нужно просто в настройках редактора указать кодировку по умолчанию для открывания.

Comment: @KoVadim: этот комментарий должен быть ответом. Только уберите лишнее «н» из слова «латиница».